# ImageMagick invalid_image, not authorized and error/constitute.c/ReadImage/454 on main domain but not on subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, imagemagick

I have the following php code on my page:

```
$image_editor = wp_get_image_editor( 'https://smashballoon.com/wp-content/themes/smashballoon/img/smash-balloon-logo-small.png' );
var_dump( $image_editor );
```

On my main domain (say www.domainname.com), this produces the following error:

```
object(WP_Error)#4950 (2) { ["errors"]=&gt; array(1) { ["invalid_image"]=&gt; array(1) { [0]=&gt; string(134) "not authorized `//smashballoon.com/wp-content/themes/smashballoon/img/smash-balloon-logo-small.png' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/454" } } ["error_data"]=&gt; array(1) { ["invalid_image"]=&gt; string(88) "https://smashballoon.com/wp-content/themes/smashballoon/img/smash-balloon-logo-small.png" } }
```

So I cloned the site to a subdomain (say mytest.domainname.com)... and there it does NOT produce the error, but:

```
object(WP_Image_Editor_Imagick)#4595 (7) { ["image":protected]=&gt; object(Imagick)#4593 (0) { } ["file":protected]=&gt; string(88) "https://smashballoon.com/wp-content/themes/smashballoon/img/smash-balloon-logo-small.png" ["size":protected]=&gt; array(2) { ["width"]=&gt; int(357) ["height"]=&gt; int(71) } ["mime_type":protected]=&gt; string(9) "image/png" ["default_mime_type":protected]=&gt; string(10) "image/jpeg" ["quality":protected]=&gt; int(82) ["default_quality":protected]=&gt; int(82) }
```

I've asked my hosting company what the problem is... but they have no clue, so I'm asking here:
What is causing the exact same code to NOT work on my main domain, but it does work on a subdomain?
(website is cloned, including htaccess, etc.) The subdomain is set up on the same account as the main domain)

Comment: Perhaps, you need to edit your Imagemagick policy.xml file to give permission to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, after a few weeks going back and forth with the hosting company, they suddenfly found that the php.ini file had allow_url_fopen disabled.

I'll leave the question here nonetheless in case someone else stumbles on the same issue.